# Como se hace una migracion de Informix a postgressql

Tags: sql, postgresql, informix

Tengo una base de datos en informix, requiero hacer la migración a postgresql, tengo entendido que lo puedo hacer con el INSER INTO, pero quiero ver si me pueden indicar otra forma mas fácil ya que tengo mas de 70 mil registros por migrar.

Comment: Bienvenido Ivan Rodriguez a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.